# Cannot Launch Prothetheus App for RPI, Error code 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, prometheus, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to run Prometheus' standalone app on an RPI4 8GB. I am following the instructions laid out here: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-prometheus/

My prometheus.service file is this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus Server
Documentation=https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=pi
Restart=on-failure

ExecStart=/home/pi/prometheus/prometheus \
    --config.file=/home/pi/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    --storage.tsdb.path=/home/pi/prometheus/data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I try to run the service I get the following error.

```
    ● prometheus.service - Prometheus Server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-11-24 18:42:51 GMT; 2s ago
       Docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
    Process: 485265 ExecStart=/home/pi/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/home/pi/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/home/pi/prometheus/data (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 485265 (code=exited, status=2)
        CPU: 160ms

Nov 24 18:42:51 master2 systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 24 18:42:51 master2 systemd[1]: Stopped Prometheus Server.
Nov 24 18:42:51 master2 systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 24 18:42:51 master2 systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 24 18:42:51 master2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Prometheus Server.
```

What does Error Status 2 mean in this context? Is it a permission problem, or something else?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with writing `systemctl` services but (1) does user `pi` exist? (2) do the file `prometheus.yml` and folder `data` exist in `/home/pi/prometheus`? (3) does user `pi` have permissions to access them? (4) What happens if you run `prometheus --config.file=... --storage.tsdb.path=...` interactively as the user `pi`? (5) Unclear whether `journalctl` would log anything additional but have you checked?

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. There was a partial installation of Prometheus left which was blocking something